# adding users to organizational units using java in googleApps

Tags: java, google-api

i am looking for a java code sample that explains on how i can add a user to an organizational unit.
i added several units and now i would like to move the uses to the appropriate unit. 
in addition it would make life easier, if i also can retrieve all existing units with somthing like `getOrganizations()`

thanks
thomas

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample client I wrote:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2Nu5U2Cz81qY2RjMzNlODYtNmY1Yy00ZWNmLWE5NWQtM2ZhNTkyZWI0YTNi&hl=en_US

This client provides samples for all possible organization unit management operations including `retrieveAllOrganizationUnits` and should be used with GData Java library which can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list